# Alamofire - how to deal with completion blocks?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

i'm pretty new in iOS and want and using of Alamofire. I want ask following: how to call some completion block when all items (in my case users) is already handled. Completion block is in defer block

**StopsHandler.swift**

```
func requestStopsForUser(user: User, completion: (result: RequestResult, json: JSON?) -> Void) {
    alamofireManager?.request(.GET, "\(AppSettings.ApiURL)/v1/users/\(user.id)/stops.json", headers: ["Authorization": "Token token=\(user.apiKey)"]).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                completion(result: .Success, json: JSON(value))
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            if error.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                completion(result: .TimedOut, json: nil)
            } else {
                completion(result: .ConnectionFailed, json: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Main.swift**

```
func fetchUsersAndStops(completion: (result: RequestResult) -> Void ) {

    var allStopsToWrite = [[Stop]]() //for each user we have array of stops to write in model

    requestAllUsers() { result, json in
        switch result {
        case .Success:
            let users = self.usersFromJSON(json)

            for (i, user) in users.enumerate() {   
                StopsHandler.sharedInstance.requestStopsForUser(user) { result, json in
                    print("i in = \(i)")
                    switch result {
                    case .Success:
                        defer {
                            let isLastUser = (i == users.count - 1)
                            if isLastUser {
                                try! self.realm.write(transactionBlock: {
                                    for (index, stopsToWrite) in allStopsToWrite.enumerate() {
                                        users[index].stops.appendContentsOf(stopsToWrite)
                                        self.realm.add(users[index], update: true)
                                    }},
                                    completion: {
                                        completion(result: .Success) //I want to call this completion when last user is already handled.
                                })
                            }
                        }

                        guard let json = json else {return}
                        let stops = StopsHandler.sharedInstance.stopsFromJSON(json)

                        let globalStops = self.realm.objects(Stop)

                        var stopsToWrite = [Stop]()

                        for stop in stops {
                            if globalStops.filter("id = '\(stop.id)'").first == nil {
                                stopsToWrite.append(stop)
                                if let currentUserId = self.currentUser?.id {
                                    if currentUserId == user.id {
                                        user.loggedIn = true
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        allStopsToWrite.append(stopsToWrite)
                    case .TimedOut:
                        completion(result: .TimedOut)
                    case .ConnectionFailed:
                        completion(result: .ConnectionFailed)
                    }
                }
            }
        case .TimedOut:
            completion(result: .TimedOut)
        case .ConnectionFailed:
            completion(result: .ConnectionFailed)
        }
    }
}
```

I assume that my code runs in `main_queue` and i want the output the following (i have 4 users on server):

```
i in = 0
i in = 1
i in = 2
i in = 3
```

But suddenly i have the following:

```
i in = 3
i in = 1
i in = 2
i in = 0
```

And I don't know why. Any help is massively appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have 4 user, so you call the request 4 time, and you want to do something after you retrieved all 4 user, thats your question? Pretty unclear what you want to ask really

Comment: @Tj3n yes that right i want to do something after i processed all users

Comment: do you have the number of request having beforehand? like u know u need to call it 4 times?

Comment: @Tj3n no i don't have this information

Comment: Then just call the request until it return nil or empty or something and execute finishing code in the `completion(result: , json: )`, since you have no idea how many request you have to make, for the ordering then because each request transfer with different time, it's normal to have wrong ordered output

Comment: @Tj3n but how to make ordered output?

Comment: You cant, if you wanted that then you should save it in an array, wait all request finish then sort

Answer (score 0):

`Alamofire.request` does not run on the main queue. It run `asynchronously`, although the `.responseJSON` will be return on `main queue` by default to allow you to update the UI. Therefore your output is not what you expected.

If you want it to return in the order, you will have to wrap your request in a dispatch main queue.

Something like this:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(Double(0.2) * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    // your code here.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As Alarmofire is calling request in async method. That why all the request is call at a time but response time will not be same for all request.

To call all request in sequence you can call service once previous service is completed.

As we are facing same issue so we did use a dispatch_block_t to perform sequence task.

```
- (void)fetchAllUserAndStopWithCompletion:(void(^)(id resultResponse, BOOL isComplete))completion {

  // Step 1: Define default parameters and limits.
  __block NSInteger totalNumberOfUser = 4;
  __block NSInteger currentRequest = 0;
  __block dispatch_block_t t_request;

dispatch_block_t request = [^{
    // Step 2: Fetch User information for currentRequest id.
    [UserRequest fetchUserRequestWithId:<UserId or Any Unique Id>
                           successBlock:^(id resultResponse, NSError *error) {

                               currentRequest += 1;
                               // Step 3: Check for remaining request. If request is remaining then call ’t_request()’.
                               if (currentRequest < totalNumberOfUser) {
                                   // Request Remaining
                                   if (completion) {
                                       id response = (!error)?resultResponse:nil;
                                       completion(response, NO);
                                   }
                                   t_request();
                               }
                               else {
                                   // All Request Completed
                                   if (completion) {
                                       id response = (!error)?resultResponse:nil;
                                       completion(response, YES);
                                   }
                               }
                           }];

} copy];

t_request = request;
request();
}
```

Note: this will only help when you fetch each user info with different call. If you get all user information in single call then you only need to sort an user with NSSortDescriptor.

If you have any problem related to perform sequence task you can leave a comment below.